# How to force MS Word 2010 to split words anywhere

Tags: microsoft-word

I want Microsoft Word 2010 to force split words exactly where the line ends, even if it is "wrong and unreadable". Font is some monotype (Courier New).

The text is in **Text field** which has fixed width. I found some option in Text field Format - *Wrap lines inside*. But it only disables / enables whole wrapping.

The text will be printed over uniform spaced boxes, each for one letter (postal order).

Examples:

Current:

```
some text with          |
looooooooooong word     |
```

What i want:

```
some text with looooooo |
oooong word             |
```

I tried to google it for an hour, but everybody wants the exact opposite (hard spaces etc..)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure there's a more elegant way to do this, but if you make all spaces in the line non-breaking spaces (cntrl-shift-spacebar), the line will only wrap when it gets to the end of your fixed width text field. Just checked. You can do a find/replace with a normal space in the find field, and a cntrl-shift-spacebar in the replace field. Seems to do the trick.

Comment: Wow, why I didn't figure that out :) But then I have to preprocess my input data for Mail merge..
Nevertheless, if noone gives me proper solution, I will accept this one.
Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Three years on, but I have an answer.
Install Japanese language to your language settings, reboot Word 2010 and then go to paragraph options. On the Asian Typography tab check the second check-box, which says something like "Allow Latin text to wrap in the middle of a word" (I use Word 2010 in Japanese, so I'm not sure of the exact text in English).

There you go, text wrapping in the middle of words that you can toggle on and off for each paragraph.

Answer (score 3):

This is very long after your original post, but I was having the same problem. The tutorial here explains how to automatically add hyphens at line breaks: [`http://www.officetooltips.com/word/tips/using_automatic_hyphenation.html`](http://www.officetooltips.com/word/tips/using_automatic_hyphenation.html)

> Open Page Layout tab, in the Page Setup group, click Hyphenation and choose Hyphenation Options

You will be presented with a dialog where you can set up automatic hyphenation for your document.

Comment: this will hyphenate according to grammatic rules. The question is about how to ignore these rules.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same problem. The only solution I've found so far is to insert a "text box" into the document and paste the text into it. Not sure if that feature was in Word 2010 as I'm using 2017.

Comment: Seems like a suggestion to use *Text field* instead of bare document. I have actually used *Text field*, but words do not split in half. Your *Text box* (different component?) actually splits words in half?

Comment: It wraps at both spaces and the right side of the text box which is not exactly what I wanted but it's close enough. I was actually doing this in Outlook but it should work in Word too. It can be found on the Insert tab, Text section.